# Unable to fetch UI due to bean validation error getting BindingException

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am getting below error when I am hitting '/signup' API after '/index' API. I have gone through many links. I found mentioned in various resources that the issue is the order of @Valid and BindingResult param needs to be maintained and I see it already in my code still I am unable to find what exactly the problem is. Please help me resolve this issue:

```
2021-05-31 19:37:40.721  WARN 10224 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 5 errors
Field error in object 'journeyFoodOrder' on field 'contactNoOfGuide': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.journeyFoodOrder.contactNoOfGuide,NotNull.contactNoOfGuide,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [journeyFoodOrder.contactNoOfGuide,contactNoOfGuide]; arguments []; default message [contactNoOfGuide]]; default message [Mobile No Of Guide is mandatory]
Field error in object 'journeyFoodOrder' on field 'nameOfCenter': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.journeyFoodOrder.nameOfCenter,NotBlank.nameOfCenter,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [journeyFoodOrder.nameOfCenter,nameOfCenter]; arguments []; default message [nameOfCenter]]; default message [Name Of Center is mandatory]
Field error in object 'journeyFoodOrder' on field 'mealRetrievalTime': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.journeyFoodOrder.mealRetrievalTime,NotNull.mealRetrievalTime,NotNull.java.util.Date,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [journeyFoodOrder.mealRetrievalTime,mealRetrievalTime]; arguments []; default message [mealRetrievalTime]]; default message [Meal retrieval time is mandatory]
Field error in object 'journeyFoodOrder' on field 'nameOfGuide': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.journeyFoodOrder.nameOfGuide,NotBlank.nameOfGuide,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [journeyFoodOrder.nameOfGuide,nameOfGuide]; arguments []; default message [nameOfGuide]]; default message [Name Of Guide is mandatory]
Field error in object 'journeyFoodOrder' on field 'dateOfDeparture': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.journeyFoodOrder.dateOfDeparture,NotNull.dateOfDeparture,NotNull.java.util.Date,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [journeyFoodOrder.dateOfDeparture,dateOfDeparture]; arguments []; default message [dateOfDeparture]]; default message [Departure date is mandatory]]
```

Controller Code

```
@Controller
public class JourneyFoodOrderController {
    
    private final JourneyFoodOrderRepository journeyFoodOrderRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JourneyFoodOrderController(JourneyFoodOrderRepository journeyFoodOrderRepository) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.journeyFoodOrderRepository = journeyFoodOrderRepository;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(@Valid JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder) {
        return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addJourneyFoodOrder")
    //@Valid AccountForm form, BindingResult result,  (binding=false) Account account
    public String addJourneyFoodOrder(@Valid JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
        }
        model.addAttribute("journeyFoodOrder", journeyFoodOrder);
        journeyFoodOrderRepository.save(journeyFoodOrder);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String showJourneyFoodOrderList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("journeyFoodOrders", journeyFoodOrderRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }

}
```

View Code

```html
 <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                    <div id="successMessage"class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                      Order saved successfully
                    </div>
                    <div id="failureMessage" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                      Invalid data
                    </div>
                    <form action="#" th:action="@{/addJourneyFoodOrder}" th:object="${journeyFoodOrder}"method="post">
                        <h2 class="mb-5">New Order</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nameOfCenter">Name of Center</label>
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{nameOfCenter}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of Center">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nameOfCenter')}" th:errors="*{nameOfCenter}"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nameOfGuide">Name of Guide/Teacher</label>
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{nameOfGuide}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of Guide">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nameOfGuide')}" th:errors="*{nameOfGuide}"></span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="headCount">Head count</label>
                            <input type="number" th:field="*{headCount}" class="form-control" placeholder="Head count">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('headCount')}" th:errors="*{headCount}"></span>
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></span>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dateOfJourney">Mobile No Of Guide</label>
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{contactNoOfGuide}" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No Of Guide">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contactNoOfGuide')}" th:errors="*{contactNoOfGuide}"></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dateOfDeparture">Date of departure</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" th:field="*{dateOfDeparture}" id="date" placeholder="Choose departure date"/>
                                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dateOfDeparture')}" th:errors="*{dateOfDeparture}"></span>
                                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date">Meal retrieval time:</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" th:field="*{mealRetrievalTime}" id="date" placeholder="Choose meal retrieval date and time"/>
                                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mealRetrievalTime')}" th:errors="*{mealRetrievalTime}"></span>
                                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Model

```
    @Entity
public class JourneyFoodOrder{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @NotBlank(message="Name Of Center is mandatory")
    private String nameOfCenter;

    @NotBlank(message="Name Of Guide is mandatory")
    private String nameOfGuide;
    
    @NotNull(message="Head Count is mandatory")
    private int headCount;
    
    @NotNull(message="Mobile No Of Guide is mandatory")
    private String contactNoOfGuide;
    
    @NotNull(message="Departure date is mandatory")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    
    @NotNull(message="Meal retrieval time is mandatory")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a")
    private Date mealRetrievalTime;

    @NotNull(message="Thepla Count is mandatory")
    private int thepla;
    
    @NotNull(message="Puri Count is mandatory")
    private int puri;
    
    @NotNull(message="Roti Count is mandatory")
    private int roti;

    @NotNull(message="Achar count is mandatory")
    private int achar;
    
    @NotNull(message="Jam count is mandatory")
    private int jam;
    
    @NotNull(message="Bread count is mandatory")
    private int bread;
    
    @NotNull(message="Other items count is mandatory")
    private int others;
 //..............setters and getters   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `@Valid` annotation on the `@GetMapping` method:

```
@GetMapping("/signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(@Valid JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder) {
        return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
    }
```

This indicates that `JourneyFoodOrder` already should be valid when showing the form for the first time, which is never true. Use this in stead:

```
@GetMapping("/signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder) {
        return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
    }
```

I personally find it clearer to do this:

```
@GetMapping("/signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("journeyFoodOrder", new JourneyFoodOrder());
        return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
    }
```

But both will work fine.

Additional notes:

1. You need to use `@ModelAttribute` for your form data object parameter in the `@PostMapping` method:

```
public String addJourneyFoodOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute("journeyFoodOrder") JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder, BindingResult result, Model model) {
 ...
}
```

2. After fixing the `@GetMapping` method, you will run into another problem because `add-journeyFoodOrder.html` has this line that should be removed:

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></span>
```

3. You might want to use a dedicated form data object to bind to the HTML form instead of using your entity directly. See [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) for more information on that.

Comment: I tried the same but it is not working `code`  @PostMapping("/addJourneyFoodOrder")
    public String addJourneyFoodOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute("journeyFoodOrder")JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
        }
        model.addAttribute("journeyFoorOrder", journeyFoodOrder);
        journeyFoodOrderRepository.save(journeyFoodOrder);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

Comment: please do let me know what exactly wrong I am doing.

Comment: No idea. Maybe you can put a minimal sample that reproduces the problem on GitHub?

Comment: PLease find code here[link](https://github.com/mshivam76/journeyfood)

Comment: I have gone through the link you have mentioned. That is really nice article, I have a few questions about why to create **UserCreationParameters** (as it's mentioned in the article that for immutability but using directly entity **User**  class will also give us the same result), then why bother by creating an extra class?